# bookworm Installation fails with “unmet dependencies” Error

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

```
$ apt install bookworm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bookworm : Depends: libgranite3 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
$ apt policy bookworm libgranite3
bookworm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.6-0~42~ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
     0.6-0~42~ubuntu16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bookworm-team/bookworm/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libgranite3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

---

```
$ lsb_release -sd
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

Comment: The `bookworm` package depends on `libgranite3`, which is available in 16.04. only under the name `libgranite2` (see [libgranite packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=libgranite)). This is a problem the developers need to solve, so I contacted them about the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I contacted the developer behind [ppa:bookworm-team/bookworm](https://launchpad.net/~bookworm-team/+archive/ubuntu/bookworm), but apparently he **doesn't maintain bookworm anymore**. Instead he pointed me to [ppa:bablu-boy/bookworm-daily](https://launchpad.net/~bablu-boy/+archive/ubuntu/bookworm-daily), where the software is availabe in a maintained state.

To deinstall (traces of) the old program and remove the faulty PPA, follow these steps:

- deinstall the program

  ```
  sudo apt remove bookworm
  ```
- remove the old PPA

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:bookworm-team/bookworm
  ```

To add the new PPA and install the program, do:

- add the new PPA

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bablu-boy/bookworm-daily
  ```
- update the package sources

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```
- install `bookworm`

  ```
  sudo apt install bookworm
  ```

Comment: Old repo is still maintained. Probably by BabluBoy

Comment: @MurshidAhmed It seems like that, so the difference is that `ppa:bablu-boy/bookworm-daily` ships the last version whereas `ppa:bookworm-team/bookworm` has an older, presumably more stable(?) one. However, the latter until today still contains version 0.6-0~42, which at least in Ubuntu 16.04 causes the error OP experienced. If you use external sources you might as well use up-to-date software from there IMO. Thanks for adding this information though!

Comment: No problem. Actually, I faced the same error on my 17.10 too.

Answer (score 4):

This didn't work for me. It failed with an unmet dependency on `libgranite4`.
I was able to get bookworm to install by adding the `repo ppa:elementary-os/stable`, which I found in [this post](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/09/install-bookworm-ebook-reader-via-ppa-in-ubuntu-16-04-17-04/#comment-3665012).

Answer (score 1):

[Their website has a workaround](https://babluboy.github.io/bookworm/#install) for this issue. What you need to do is to add the elementary-os repository to apt-get as well:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install com.github.babluboy.bookworm
```

Then (according to their website) you can remove elementary-os if you'd like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

Answer (score 0):

(This is tested on ubuntu 16.04)
As `Jim G.` said you have to add the **Elementary OS Team** PPA to the apt repo list. I dont know why, maybe this app is for elementary os but this works:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bookworm
```

Second option is to install `aptitude` then `aptitude install` it. Aptitude seems to handle this situations:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install bookworm
```

Comment: Please add the Ubuntu version you tested this on. The PPA I recommended contains packages for every currently supported version (except 14.04), if it doesn't work for you please leave a comment on my answer and [inform the PPA owner](https://answers.launchpad.net/~bablu-boy) so he can work on the issue. Adding the Elementary OS PPA to your Ubuntu installation may result in problems.